# Exception: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method

Tags: java, классы

Вопрос от новичка, изучающего java:

Написал вот такой код:

```
public class Worker {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public String get(String firstName, String lastName) {
return lastName + " " + firstName;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = get("Иван","Иванов");
    System.out.println(name);
}
}
```

Пишет ошибку на строке 9:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method get(String, String) from the type Worker

    at Worker.main(Worker.java:31)
```

В чём проблема, как исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Worker {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public static String get(String firstName, String lastName) {
return lastName + " " + firstName;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = get("Иван","Иванов");
    System.out.println(name);
}
}
```

или

```
public class Worker {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public String get(String firstName, String lastName) {
return lastName + " " + firstName;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Worker w = new Worker();
    String name = w.get("Иван","Иванов");
    System.out.println(name);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделай метод статическим.
И, кроме того, лучше значение

> lastName + " " + firstName

присваивай некоторой переменной типа Strin и возвращай ее.

Comment: а зачем присваивать? компилятор и JVM все и так заинлайнят